# Inserting Variable in to link

Tags: php, html

I am trying to insert a variable in to my link and it will not display properly.

I have tried using single quotes and escaping and still can't seem to get it to work.

```
                $cid = $row['id'];
                echo $cid; // This displays what I need no problem
                echo '<a href="loggedin.php.php?id="'.$row['id'].'"> // This does not add the $cid to the link
    Link
    </a>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is close, you simply don't want to close off the link's `"` so early.

You'll want to *open* the link in the first part, then *close* it in the final part:

```
echo '<a href="loggedin.php.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Link</a>';
```

Comment: Or - `echo "<a href='loggedin.php.php?id=$row[\'id\']'>Link</a>";`

Answer (score 1):

```
            $cid = $row['id'];
            echo $cid; // This displays what I need no problem
            echo '<a href="loggedin.php.php?id="'.$row['id'].'">Link</a>';
```

Perhaps a better way to do this:

```
echo sprintf('<a href="loggedin.php.php?id=%d">%s</a>', $row['id'], 'Link');
```